# Does the universe regenerate every kalpa (4.32 billion years) or every half kalpa?

Tags: kalpa

As far as I understand, a kalpa is 4.32 billion years long. In that time, the universe is destroyed and created anew. In [a video from Extra Mythology](https://youtu.be/HDGQ713Zz54?t=57), they state:

"It is told that the universe regenerates in cycles of every 2.16 billion years and at the end of each cycle, Shiva destroys it."

2.16 billion years is exactly half a kalpa. Is there any specific reason they chose half a kalpa here? Are they wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe? Nobody references half a kalpa here and they talk about about the max age of the universe being 1 kalpa, so I guess that means Extra Mythology was mistaken. I still wonder what would make them think the universe in cycles of 2.16 billion years though.

Comment: Refer srimad Bhagvatam here https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/12/4/2/. Says 1 kalpa = 1 day of Brahma. Next page 12.4.3 says night is as long as day that’s where destruction happens. Universe’s destruction? That can be debated